# Store Add-in Window Does Not Open

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, add-in

When I click the Store button in Add-in group (Home tab), it doesn't open the Store window instead, it opens a web page in my default browser. My purpose is to upload an xml file from my files.

Comment: I believe nobody would tell you what's wrong with your Outlook Desktop. Are you using Office 365 account?

Comment: No. It says here Microsoft Exchange

Comment: Where is it says? In the status bar of the Outlook it will say "Connected to Microsoft Exchange" always. Same for account property. When you go to "File" tab -> "Info" -> "Account Settings", does it say "Access this account on the web" [https://outlook.office365.com/owa/](https://outlook.office365.com/owa/) ? Can you log with your account into Office 365?

Comment: it says "Access this account on the web. https://mail.(domainname).net/owa"

Comment: OK, now it's clear. If your company uses on-prem Exchange it's up to admin to allow you to install the apps or not. But this is not all. Only Exchange 2013 and 2016 are supported. And even more after admin grant you permission to install custom manifest.xml, this manifest has to be at certain level API. Bottom line, there is nothing wrong with your Outlook, go to your Exchange admin. Also you may try to go to the URL for OWA and inside settings look for "Manage Add-ins" and try from there.

Comment: Yes. We have Exchange 2016. What do you mean certain level API? Also Ive tried the OWA and in the Manage Add-ins it says "There was a problem loading your options". How is that?

Comment: Manifest.xml file would have requirement for Office.js API as of `<Set Name="MailBox" MinVersion="1.x" />`. The `MinVersion` defined by manifest is impotent for add-in to work, but may not be supported by your Exchange Server depend on CU (patch) level of the server. Look up the net to get information on server requirements for requested API of your add-in. See if your server version meets this criteria.